# How to validate a workflow in my database table

Tags: mysql, validation, workflow, etl

I have a MySQL table, which contains the state changement history of my object. Something like :

1. id_object ; creation
2. id_object ; validation
3. id_object ; finalization

(of course my workflow is much more complex, it's only for the example)

There are some bugs in the code which generates this history, and the chronology is not respected. I can have for example :

1. id_object ; creation
2. id_object ; finalization
3. id_object ; validation

I am looking for a tool which can :

1. Look for these anomalies and correct them
2. Automatically detect these anomalies (CRON or whatever) and notice the admin

I thought that an ETL was the right tool to do it, but it seems it is impossible to do it with Talend or with Pentaho.

Do you have any idea on the right tool to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have timestamp associated with 'creation', 'validation' and 'finalization' or do you rely on the unsorted table data to determine the sequence?

Comment: Yes, to bring some keys to the reflexion, I have these data : id_historic, timestamp, id_transition, final_state. id_transition is something like "validation" whereas state is "validated". Two problems in my table : the states are not always in the chronological order, and the transitions are not consistent (sometimes, the transition "validation" leads to the "created" state)